# Check a radio button by clicking the <a> associated with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, dom-events

I have a set of elements like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input type="radio" name="location-radio" />
     </span>
    <a data-id="" class="list-group-item location-list-group-item">
            <span class="badge">0</span>Takeaway
    </a>
</div>
```

Whenever an `<a>` element with the class `.location-list-group-item` is clicked the radio button above it must be checked.
The code I am using to do this is:

```
$(function(){
    $(".location-list-group-item").click(function(){
        alert("Hit");
        $(event.target).prev('span.input-group-addon:nth-child(1)').prop("checked", true)
    });
});
```

The click event is working I just cant get the box to check.
I have tried many ways so far but none seem to work.
I have the latest version of jQuery and I am at a loss.

EDIT:
Thank you all for your responses, you all helped me learn more about selecting elements :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $(".location-list-group-item").click(function(){   
        $(this).prev().children('input[type=radio]').prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9MMLV/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5PNyL/)</kbd>

```
$(event.target).prev('span.input-group-addon').find('input:radio').prop("checked", true);
```

---

you can use [$(this)](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/) instead of `$(event.target)`

```
$(this).prev('span.input-group-addon').find('input:radio').prop("checked", true);
```

---

```
.prev('span.input-group-addon').find('input:radio')
                                 ^ //find input radio inside prev span with class input-group-addon
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $(".location-list-group-item").click(function () {
        $(this).prev('span.input-group-addon').find('input').prop("checked", true)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $(".location-list-group-item").click(function(){
        alert("Hit");
        $(event.target).prev('span.input-group-addon').find(':radio').prop("checked", true)
    });
});
```